# Scss adding new class is not reflecting in browser

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Below is my sCSS class. I am adding a new span class in between div Test2 but span class is not reflected in browse F12 nor I can see the span changes. I am new to CSS any help would be very useful

```
    <div class="Test">
    <div class="Test1">
    <div class="Test2">
<span class="hai"></span>
</div>
    <div class="Test3">
</div>
</div>
```

css file

```
 .Test{
  margin:0 px
    .Test1{
    float:left
    }

   .Test2{
    float:left
.hai{
   background-color:balack
  }
    }
  .Test3{
    float:left
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for scss to work, your file must be saved with a .scss extension in your project with required scss dependencies, Also, the syntax errors are there due to which there might be a possibility of styles not reflecting on real-time, few syntactical corrections done:

```css
.Test{
  margin:0 px;
    .Test1{
    float:left;
    }

   .Test2{
    float:left;
.hai{
   background-color:balack
   /*corrected style*/
 background-color:black;
  }
    }
  .Test3{
    float:left
    }
}
```